# How to create a "pager" to go through arbitrary html, one "page" at a time

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface

I have some text I'd like to publish, but feel like the "ebook file format" route is just too ridged and doesn't add much, considering what it asks of the user (install reader, download, open... Try another reader... Use iTunes to transfer a file...)

For my purposes, I think it'd be nice to try to create a minimal "browser-native" ebook reading experience. I have book-like content that is formatted in a pretty obvious way. Forgetting about chapters and all that, just imagine a long series of html paragraphs of varying length.

What would be cool is if I could have a `<div>` to contain the "page" (sort of the book "view port"), and have Next/Previous buttons that scroll through the text one div-hight at a time, without any animation (so it looks like you are flipping pages and not scrolling.)

I worry about lines of text being cut in half instead of dividing the text at per-line boundaries, which I bet is a fixable problem!

Any ideas about how to do this in a clean, minimal way, or maybe suggestions for "frameworks" that exist for this purpose? I'd also be open to an in-browser (e.g.) ePUB viewer if a good something-like-that exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really open minded and creative, I would suggest you to try or use as insipration the navigation of "RevealJS".

RevealJS
https://revealjs.com/
(It can be used without the Slides software, you can use it completely programattically)

Usage Examples:
https://cgi1.gitlab.io/g2scoring-presentation/
https://www.jmrenouard.fr/sshcookbook/#/13/1

(Use Arrows, Press ESC, Click, Press M ... All of those, can be customized)

Comment: That's a pretty excellent starting point. Node is a turnoff for me (as an "extreme minimalist"...probably to my detriment) but the results are amazing. I'll keep poking around at examples. Thank you!